# How can I mock path with path.win32 in jest?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, mocking

I want my test suite to work as if it was on Windows platform. Unfortunately, a lot of dependencies use `path` module. I want to mock it with `path.win32` implementation. However, this approach doesn't work:

```
const winPath = require("path").win32;
jest.mock("path", () => winPath);
```

> ReferenceError: Cannot access 'winPath' before initialization

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`jest.mock()` should work. The below example shows how to mock the `win32.normalize()` method.

```
const winPath = require("path").win32;

jest.mock('path', () => {
  return {
    ...(jest.requireActual('path') as typeof import('path')),
    win32: {
      normalize: jest.fn(),
    }
  }
})

describe('74717157', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    winPath.normalize.mockImplementation(() => 'override the original implementation')
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(winPath.normalize)).toBeTruthy();
    expect(winPath.normalize()).toBe('override the original implementation')
  })
})
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/74717157/index.test.ts (10.557 s)
  74717157
    ✓ should pass (1 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        14.116 s
```

Comment: I need to mock the entire module, not just individual functions. And it's not really "mock" per se, but to fill in the implementation for specific platform.